# webClient.DownloadString() загрузил не весь html код с сайта

Tags: c#

Есть сайт https://ekb.zarplata.ru/resume

Я хочу загрузить его код в файл. 
Для этого делаю так:

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
 {
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://somesite.com/default.html");
    File.WriteAllText (@"D:\path.txt", contents);
 }
```

В итоге в этом файле оказался далеко не весь html код с сайта. Например, если перейти на страницу, которую я привел выше, то видно, что там 50 резюме, к тому же у каждого резюме есть Фамилия. В файле оказалось только 25 резюме, причем фамилий нету вовсе.

Comment: Вы же видите дополнительные резюме, фамилии и так далее в браузере - который помимо загрузки начального html, выполняет javascript. Вот и грузить страницу в коде надо при помощи компонента WebBrowser https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Судя по всему, дополнительная информация грузится аяксом. Так что вам нужно или внимательно читать HTML и разбирать его логику, либо такие эмулировать браузер.

Comment: @VladD, с веб-браузером проблема в том, что по умолчанию си-шарповый класс WebBrowser содержит под собой InternetExplorer не самой последней версии, и в ней тот сайт который мне надо парсить вообще не открывается.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Угу, это дополнительная проблема. А в новом IE открывается? WebBrowser можно было как-то настроить.

Comment: @VladD, в новом открывается, но я никак не найду как настроить, уже третий день ищу)

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Эта информация пробегала по сайту, но я не запомнил точный рецепт. Возможно, имеет смысл задать отдельный вопрос именно про это: как заставить WebBrowser притворяться новой версией IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, надо отловить все запросы, которые происходят при загрузке страницы.

Среди них довольно легко найти дозапрос информации:

https://api.zp.ru/v1/resumes/?geo_id=994&limit=50&state=1

Запрос возвращает всю информацию в виде json, разбирайте сразу её, незачем парсить страницу.

UPD: Для просмотра запросов я пользуюсь расширением http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/ для firefox. Расширение собственно и выдало мне эту ссылку.

Содержимое json можно скормить сайту типа http://json2csharp.com/ и получить вполне рабочую модель. Модель надо занести в проект, чтобы её можно было построить, верхнеуровневый объект называется `RootObject`.

Дальше берем сборку http://www.newtonsoft.com/json и получаем модель в коде:

```
  var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.zp.ru/v1/resumes/?geo_id=994&limit=50&state=1");
  var root = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Дальше, я лично изучаю содержимое переменной `root` просто в отладке в окне `locals`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Минимальная информация, которая отображается на сайте, тут точно есть. У некоторых может будут даже фотографии, не искал.

Comment: а еще из этого запроса следует, что у сайта есть API, и лучше воспользоваться именно им, наверняка есть его подробное описание, правда скорее всего не задаром

Comment: @rdorn ну, я не стал искать за автора, хочет "раскопок" - пусть копает.

Comment: @Monk, объясните чуть подробнее, пожалуйста. Я просто совсем новичок в этом деле. Вот страница, которую вы скинули, как вы на нее попали? И к тому же, я по ней сделал поиск, там тоже нет ни имен, ни даже профессий уже. Но видимо я что то не понимаю. Что за запрос нужен, который вернет json со всей нужной информацией. Хотя бы идея какая?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Monk, класс, спасибо большое! Вот только еще вопрос: а можно как то автоматизировать получение той ссылки, которую вы через расширение получили? То есть получить ее в коде с# и использовать в DownloadString?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров а это зависит от того, что вы хотите получить. Скорее всего, ссылка генерируется по каким то правилам, попробуйте сами на сайте позапрашивать разные резюме и полистать страницы. Определите логику - сможете генерировать ссылку сами. Это мне прямо сейчас за вас делать лень.

Comment: @Monk, конечно не надо делать, понимаю) я думал может в С# есть какая нибудь готовая функция для этого. Тогда бы вы мне просто ее название сказали) ведь расширение как то программного пооучает эту ссылку. Хотя оно конечно не на с# написано наверняка

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров это логика конкретного сайта, нет в коробке у c# функций для этого, естественно.

Comment: @Monk, тоже воспользовался расширением, но там же он очень много выдает запросов. Как разобраться, какой из них мне нужен?

Comment: @Monk, я думал может надо посмотреть где в Content-Type json, но таких запросов тоже штук 5 набралось. И они вроде ничем не отличаются от того, с которого вы взяли ссылку. Как же вы поняли что это именно тот запрос, который нужен?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров запросов с json - пять. Первые 4 довольно неконкретные, а в этом сразу видно - он запрашивает 50 штук (и явно отображается на сайте 50 резюме) и запрос явно к api.zp.ru, т.е. это запрос к АПИ, а не авторизации или ещё чему как предыдущие.

Comment: @Monk, ага, то есть нет никакого атрибута, увидев который можно сразу сказать что это то что нужно? Я понял. Просто проглядывать значения атрибутов и догадываться нужно. Благо догадаться можно) Спасибо!